# How to display php error like Codeigniter?

Tags: php

I am working on PHP online IDE using core PHP. How  to display PHP error like CodeIgniter when user tests php code?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What does the screenshot show? Is that with or without CodeIgniter?

Comment: I guess it's error handling in CodeIgniter. Please provide more details next time. In order to have well-formatted error messages it is required to write an own error handler. [w3schools - PHP Error Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp)

Comment: I tried my best to make it **codeignitor like** but you may try out my answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for **exactly** like codeignitor because I have never used it, but:

**Method 1**

You can edit php.ini

```
; String to output before an error message.
error_prepend_string = "<font color=ff0000><b>An Error Occured</b></font><i> Found an error as follows:</i><br><code>"

; String to output after an error message.
error_append_string = "</code>"
```

You may edit the HTML and use some ways(like js,though,I don't know if it is a good idea) to make it look better

**Method 2**

Use a custom handler:

function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{

```
$sev = "";

$errorType = array (
           E_ERROR            => 'ERROR',
           E_WARNING        => 'WARNING',
           E_PARSE          => 'PARSING ERROR',
           E_NOTICE         => 'NOTICE',
           E_CORE_ERROR     => 'CORE ERROR',
           E_CORE_WARNING   => 'CORE WARNING',
           E_COMPILE_ERROR  => 'COMPILE ERROR',
           E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'COMPILE WARNING',
           E_USER_ERROR     => 'USER ERROR',
           E_USER_WARNING   => 'USER WARNING',
           E_USER_NOTICE    => 'USER NOTICE',
           E_STRICT         => 'STRICT NOTICE',
           E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  => 'RECOVERABLE ERROR'
           );

if(!isset($errorType($errno))
{ 
    $sev = "Unknown";
}
else
{
    $sev = $errorType[$errno];
}
echo "<div style= 'border-style: solid;border-color: #98bf21;'>";
echo "<b>A PHP Error was enccounter</b>";
echo "<li>Severity: $sev";
echo "<li>Message: $errstr";
echo "<li>Filename: $errfile";
echo "<li>Line NUmber: $errline";
echo "</div>";
/* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
return true;
}

function shutdown() {

$isError = false;

if ($error = error_get_last()){
switch($error['type']){
    case E_ERROR:
    case E_CORE_ERROR:
    case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        $isError = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($isError){
    myErrorHandler($error['type'],$error['message'],$error['file'],$error['file'])
    }
}
```

And set it as

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

Check it with this:

```
un_defined_function(100);
```

[More Info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: PHP says: 
`The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.`

Comment: @JayeshVekariya Used another trick to make it do.. check the new code segment to make it as your wish